# Raw SQL queries and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I migrate my application to ASP.NET MVC Core and Entity Framework Core and i found problem. I have raw SQL query to entity like this

```
var rawSQL = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SomeModel>("Raw SQL Query").ToList();
```

But there is no `SqlQuery<T>` in `context.Database`. Do you have solution for this problem?

Comment: Is `dbContext` properly initialized as `Entities`?

Comment: @MatchesMalone Yes, normal LINQ queries working properly

Comment: see my answer below on how to use an extension method to use parameterized (or not) SQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you add `using Microsoft.Data.Entity;`
because there is an extension method you could use.

```
var rawSQL = dbContext.SomeModels.FromSql("your SQL");
```

Even better, instead using raw SQL (at risk of SQL injections attacks) this FromSql method allows you to use parameterized queries like:

```
dbContext.SomeModels.FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs WHERE Name = @p0", blogName);
```

Comment: Working well but its strange calling SQL queries from specific entity model than generally database. About injections attacks i know and i'm using SQL parameters but i wanted to show simple problem in example. Thanks

Comment: @iberodev How would you do it if your sql query contains two tables?

Comment: @nam as shown here: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/raw-sql.html#composing-with-linq
by adding an `.Include(b => b.Posts)` you are joining with another table

Comment: Just a note, for Entity Framework Core, I had to include the namespace: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Comment: what about querying against `DbContext` instead of `DeSet`? @iberodev