# Include all the properties from all the inherited classes using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When using EF6, I was using lazy loading so I never had this issue, but with EFCore, I don't know if this is possible with a single query.

I have the following class structure

```
class A { public B b; }
class B { public ICollection<C> list_c; }
class C { public ICollection<D> list_d; }
abstract class D { public long c_id; }
class Da { public E e; }
class Db { public F f; }
```

I need a list of all the `D` objects, but with access to their `e` and `f` properties respectively. I have a working query at the moment where I query `_db.D` over a list of `c_id`'s that I fetch using the first half of the query below, but with that approach, I send one query to get all the `c_id`'s and then one query per type (I have 4 types).

I was wondering if I can make it work with one call that looks something like this:

```
_db.As.Include(x => x.b)
      .ThenInclude(x => x.list_c)
      .ThenInclude(x => x.list_d)
      // some magic here
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=> x.Id = model.Id);
```

EDIT:

At the moment this is how I make the list:

```
var a = await _db.As.Include(x => x.b)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.list_c)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=> x.Id = model.Id);

var result = await _db.Ds.OfType<Da>()
                         .Include(x=>x.e)
                         .Where(x=>a.b.list_c.Any(y=>y.Id == x.c_id))
                         .Select(x=>(D)x)
                   .Concat(_db.Ds.OfType<Db>()
                         .Include(x=>x.f)
                         .Where(x=>a.b.list_c.Any(y=>y.Id == x.c_id))
                         .Select(x=>(D)x)).
                   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Not my first choice, but as an alternative you may consider to use raw sql, views or stored procedures for difficult queries. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305825/raw-sql-queries-and-entity-framework-core

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3910 this would allow you to write Include/ThenInclude on derived types in 2.1 release

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using Entity Framework Core if you have that option. Check the roadmap at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap - It currently doesn't have lazy loading to name of its (very annoying) shortcomings.

You can have your data access layer in a .NET 4.6 project and have your consuming project(s), even if the consuming is based on Core, reference that project without difficulty.

Comment: I'd love to be able to use the full framework, but the project is suppose to be .NET Core only. This is pretty much the most complex query I'm writing so I can live with my current solution until they add Lazy Loading.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the decision to make it Core only?

Comment: Would love to explain it, but not my decision to make :)

Comment: Roger that! In that case I recommend keeping an eye on the roadmap. Sadly they've not even committed to make lazy loading happen this year, but they will try their very best :(

Comment: I am following the roadmap (mostly because of lazy loading) but actually [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3910) is the feature I should be waiting for :)